# How to run a set of commands on 170 files simultaneously?

Tags: linux

I want to run the below set of commands on 170 different .txt files at the same time. How do I do that on linux?

```
awk '{ if ($2 == "T") { print } }' A0FGR8.txt | sort -t $'\t' -k5,5rn | head > A0FGR8_T.txt   
awk '{ if ($2 == "S") { print } }' A0FGR8.txt | sort -t $'\t' -k5,5rn | head > A0FGR8_S.txt
awk '{ if ($2 == "Y") { print } }' A0FGR8.txt | sort -t $'\t' -k5,5rn | head > A0FGR8_Y.txt
cat A0FGR8_*.txt > A0FGR8_sorted.txt                                
sed -i '1 i\Position\tCode\tKinase\tPeptide\tScore\tCutoff' A0FGR8_sorted.txt
```

Comment: step 1, edit the `awk`: `awk '$2 == "T"' A0FGR8.txt` will work just fine.

Comment: It just created one file named *_T.txt                                                                                   But it should create 170 files with name_T.txt